# How to get the name of Active Local Network without using network utilities?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Is there a file in Linux which stores the name (the SSID) of the local network to which I'm connected to.

I do not want to use any of the network utilities like *nmcli* or *iwgetid* or IP to get this information.

I checked the */sys/class/net*. Files there can provide the status of the connection, but I cannot find the SSID of the network there.

I also checked the */etc/NetworkManager/system-connections*. But it has all the networks that I have connected to in the past and not just the current local network I am connected to. Is there a way to get the Active Network SSID?

I believe that the utilities like *nmcli* must use some files to get this information. I want to use the same file (if that is the case).

OS: Ubuntu, Raspbian

Comment: You've not provided any OS, product & release details.  You mention *Network Manager* but it's not used by all Ubuntu products, so please be precise & provide the Ubuntu product/release you are asking about.

Comment: @guiverc
The OS can be Ubuntu or Raspbian.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *If you want to ask about Raspbian or Ubuntu - please use SE Unix & Linux where both are on-topic*

Comment: You didn't provide any specific details; Ubuntu has different products, some use *Network Manager* but others do not; so please be precise; Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Core, Ubuntu Desktop, what release etc.

Comment: I don't have any specific OS request. Looking for generic answer. But since you asked, consider Ubuntu server since that can be installed on RPi. All I want to know is that if there is a file that I can simply read to get the name of Active Local Network. Or if there is some other way to get this info without using Network Utilities.

Comment: Ubuntu Server doesn't include *Network Manager* (you can refer https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.manifest for a list of what's included) so mention of that makes little sense (*it's not on Ubuntu Core either of course*)

Comment: I have checked "/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections" on Raspbian. May be Ubuntu Server does not have it. But I want some generic answer (if there is). Please let me know if it is not possible to simply read from some file.